# Wordpress Underscore theme error

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

```
function wp_is_stream( $path ) { $wrappers = stream_get_wrappers(); $wrappers_re = '(' . join('|', $wrappers) . ')'; return preg_match( "!^$wrappers_re://! ", $path ) === 1; }
```

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3266603443 bytes) in H:\xamp\htdocs\grafteach\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5160

whats the problem when trying to go to admin panel it give this error?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is fixed.

[Wordpress/ stream_get_wrappers causes crash](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72451)